# Cannot access the record from mongo db after authentication at server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

First, I started the mongod. Then on mongo, created the user name, password, roles to the  database, here is the code

```js
> use testProjectDB
switched to db testProjectDB
  >
  db.getUsers()[{
    "_id": "testProjectDB.user",
    "user": "user",
    "db": "testProjectDB",
    "roles": [{
      "role": "readWrite",
      "db": "testProjectDB"
    }]
  }]
```

At server side, authentication given as,

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var url = "mongodb://user:pwd@localhost:27017?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=testProjectDB";
mongoose.connect(url);
var connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.on('error', function() {
  throw new Error('unable to connect to database at ' + url);
});
```

the db validates the user and password, but i cannot access the record form the database,as a beginner to mongo db authentication at server side, i could not it figure out, kindly please help me out

Comment: try this - mongodb://user:pwd@localhost:27017/testProjectDB

Comment: @PuneetSingh thanks a lot, really helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use following procedure to enable auth on stand-alone mongodb deployment:

Create an administrator user

> use admin
>
> db.createUser(
>         {
>           user: "userAdmin",
>           pwd: "xxxxx",
>           roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
>         }
>       )

Modify mongod.conf file to enable auth

> security:
>
> authorization: enabled

Restart mongod service:

> sudo service mongod restart

Connect and authenticate as the user administrator

> mongo
>   use admin    db.auth("userAdmin", "xxxxx")

Create additional users as needed for your deployment:

```
use yourdb
db.createUser(
  {
    user: ""testuser"",
    pwd: ""xxxxxx"",
    roles: [ { role: ""readWrite"", db: "yourdb" }
             ]
  }
)
```

Your mongodb connection string should look like this:

> mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/testProjectDB

Additionally, you can monitor mongodb logs for any auth related info or to check if there is any issue:

> tailf /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log